# Jenkins And NodeJS Plugin - Permission Denied Error=13

Tags: java, node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm running the latest version of `Jenkins (v 1.563)` and `Node (0.10.28)`.

I have a Java project that builds fine.

When I add a pre build step as a node script ( with Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH checked), I get the following error although I have given 777 permissions to everything (node, tomcat, jenkins).

```
FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "/home/sam/Apps/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/temp/hudson5090518537487301688.js"
(in directory "/home/sam/.jenkins/jobs/WhiteSwan/workspace"): 
error=13, Permission Denied....
```

Build step "Execute NodeJS Script" marked build as failure.
When I remove the nodejs step, it builds fine. 
My Script is simple,

```
node --version
grunt --version
bower --version
```

Full Error:

```
Checking out Revision e90d7b870646165dba30bd1a663644c0292e9844 (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout
 > git checkout -f e90d7b870646165dba30bd1a663644c0292e9844
 > git rev-list e90d7b870646165dba30bd1a663644c0292e9844
[workspace] $ /home/sam/Apps/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/temp/hudson5090518537487301688.js

FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/sam/Apps/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/temp  /hudson5090518537487301688.js" (in directory "/home/sam/.jenkins/jobs/WhiteSwan   /workspace"): error=13, Permission denied

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:775)
at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.DecoratedLauncher.launch(DecoratedLauncher.java:49)
at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NpmPackagesBuildWrapper$2.launch(NpmPackagesBuildWrapper.java:88)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:355)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:362)
at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:84)
at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:42)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:745)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:909)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:676)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:518)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
... 18 more

Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I got the same error message, but I solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32544539/555455

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it without a sudo; I suppose that running **Jenkins** under root is very unsafe.

Here are the working settings:

[image]
`/var/lib/jenkins/tools` should be owned by `jenkins:jenkins`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 jenkins jenkins      4096 May 12 15:12 tools
```

If you need any nodejs package installed globally (for example, **grunt**), the easier way is to avoid jenkins window *Global npm packages to install* (it will need root permissions), but run this in linux console:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
```

It will install **grunt** for everyone and **Jenkins** will be able to use it during building process.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by running Tomcat with sudo. Please remember to create a setenv.sh file ( read more about setenv in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt)). Remember to set HOME_JRE in setenv before running tomcat with sudo.

Comment: The tomcat is the one who contains Jenkins server?