# Jenkins NodeJS plugin throws Permission Denied error

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I'm trying to CI javascript libraries in Jenkins.  I want to use the NodeJS plugin to launch some tests, but I can't work my way around this error:

```
[workspace] $ /Users/michael_case/dev/jenkins/temp/hudson4905877153282795022.js
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/michael_case/dev/jenkins/temp/hudson4905877153282795022.js" (in directory "/Users/michael_case/.jenkins/jobs/js-build/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:775)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.DecoratedLauncher.launch(DecoratedLauncher.java:49)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NpmPackagesBuildWrapper$2.launch(NpmPackagesBuildWrapper.java:88)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:355)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:362)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:84)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:42)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:756)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:159)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1710)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 18 more
```

I'm 100% positive that Jenkins is running under my user name (michael_case).  You might even notice that I've overridden java.io.tmpdir to a folder under my own home dir that Jenkins definitely has access to.

The temp file in question `hudson4905877153282795022.js` seems to be created within this job step and cleaned up immediately because I cannot look at it to check its permissions or contents.  (I even had a previous step perform `ls -la /Users/michael_case/dev/jenkins/temp` but the file was not listed)

Any thoughts?  Any suggestions for next steps?

UPDATE:

I am running the embedded Jetty server.
I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733541/jenkins-and-nodejs-plugin-permission-denied-error-13) SO question, but because I'm not running Tomcat, I don't see how it applies.

Comment: Are you running Jenkins in Tomcat container?

Comment: Embedded container, not Tomcat.  Updated question above.  Thanks!

Comment: I got the same error message, but I solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32544539/555455