# Jenkins & NodeJS plugin - Permission Denied error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, raspberry-pi

I've managed to setup a Jenkins instance on a Raspberry Pi, and have got as far as installing the NodeJS plugin before I eventually hit this stumbling block:

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test Project/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url localhost:/GITREPO/test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from localhost:/GITREPO/test
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress localhost:/GITREPO/test +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 8e6edee9fdc1e8bf754dc1a27f46c1dea3531144 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 8e6edee9fdc1e8bf754dc1a27f46c1dea3531144
 > git rev-list 8eaf1bc6a0be837100e476b33bec559b33e9997f # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5445359267004163031.sh
+ echo /usr/local/bin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
/usr/local/bin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
+ node --version
v0.10.32
+ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
+ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
[workspace] $ /tmp/hudson1009495610900642950.js
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/hudson1009495610900642950.js" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Test Project/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:802)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.DecoratedLauncher.launch(DecoratedLauncher.java:49)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NpmPackagesBuildWrapper$2.launch(NpmPackagesBuildWrapper.java:88)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:380)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:387)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:84)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJsCommandInterpreter.perform(NodeJsCommandInterpreter.java:42)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 18 more
Build step 'Execute NodeJS script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm not doing anything particularly special, this is an initial test to ensure the NodeJS plugin works:

```
var sys = require('sys');
sys.puts('NodeJS Test');
sys.puts('***********');
sys.puts('Hello World');
```

This works if I log in as the Jenkins user, and run it myself:

```
jenkins@raspberrypi:~$ node test.js
NodeJS Test
***********
Hello World
jenkins@raspberrypi:~$
```

I've trawled the internet, and cannot seem to find anything specific; pretty sure its not file permissions specifically (Workspace directory has full access to all users)

Comment: Try to add at the first of that script a line with `#!/usr/bin/node` (check if that path is correct using `which node`)

Comment: @Salem, he is not using "Execute Shell" build step, so that suggestion is quite invalid

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. For me it was the nodejs plugin configurations, under "global configurations" in jenkins. My "node" application (symlink) was located at `/usr/local/bin/node`. And my "installation directory" was set to `/usr/local/bin/`. I changed that too `/usr/local/` and it start working! :)

Note that this is when you ***aren't*** using "install automatically"-function of the nodejs plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem with Jenkins permissions,

The issue was that Jenkins couldn't write in folders that it doesn't have permissions, so I installed the **nodejs plugin** automatically in `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/`

I described in better detail here:

[Jenkins And NodeJS Plugin - Permission Denied Error=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733541/jenkins-and-nodejs-plugin-permission-denied-error-13/])